# Bootstrap-Select js plugin not showing selected item from drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap-select jQuery plugin

- http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/
- Version 1.6.3

My page contains the JS (see bottom) to populate and show the items selected from a sequence of drop downs:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group" id="SearchOptions" style="display: none;">
        <select id="ddlLocations" class="selectpicker show-tick" data-width="100%" data-size="50">
            <option value="0">All Ports</option>
            <option class="divider" disabled="disabled"></option>
            @{
                foreach (DepartFromItemBriefDto departFrom in Model.DepartFroms.Items)
                {
                    <option value="@departFrom.PortName">@departFrom.PortName</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
        <select id="ddlDates" class="selectpicker show-tick" data-width="100%" data-size="50">
            <option value="0">All Dates</option>
            <option class="divider" disabled="disabled"></option>
            @{
                foreach (DepartMonthItemBriefDto departMonth in Model.DepartMonths.Items)
                {
                    <option value="@departMonth.Id">@departMonth.Description</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
        <select id="ddlBrands" class="selectpicker show-tick" data-width="100%" data-size="50">
            <option value="0">All Brands</option>
            <option class="divider" disabled="disabled"></option>
            @{
                foreach (CruiseBrandItemBriefDto cruiseBrand in Model.CruiseBrands.Items)
                {
                    <option value="@cruiseBrand.Id">@cruiseBrand.Description</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
        <select id="ddlShips" class="selectpicker show-tick" data-width="100%" data-size="10">
            <option value="0">All Ships</option>
            <option class="divider" disabled="disabled"></option>
            @{
                foreach (ShipItemBriefDto ship in Model.Ships.Items)
                {
                    <option value="@ship.Id">@ship.Description</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</form>

<a class="btn btn-search btn-block" href="/CruiseSearch/Search" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="phone"> Search</span></a>
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //Hook up all the change events
        $("#ddlBrands").change(function() {
            $.get("/CruiseSearch/CruiseBrandSelected", { aBrandId: $(this).val() });

            //Get the list of ships within the brand
            var $jqGetShipList = $.get("/CruiseSearch/GetShipsListByBrand", { aBrandId: $(this).val() });
            $jqGetShipList.done(function(aData) {
                var $shipsDropDown = $('#ddlShips');
                $shipsDropDown.empty();

                $.each(aData, function(aNdx, aItem) {
                    $shipsDropDown.append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", aItem.Id)
                        .text(aItem.Value));
                });

                //Ensure the styling on the drop down refreshes itself
                $shipsDropDown.selectpicker('refresh');
            });
        });

        $("#ddlDates").change(function() {
            $.get("/CruiseSearch/DepartMonthSelected", { aDateId: $(this).val() });
        });

        $("#ddlLocations").change(function() {
            $.get("/CruiseSearch/DepartFromSelected", { aPortName: $(this).val() });
        });

        $("#ddlShips").change(function() {
            $.get("/CruiseSearch/ShipSelected", { aShipId: $(this).val() });
        });

        //As we can come in here via a navigation backwards in the browser history ensure they are all called once
        //so that the front end and the back end match up
        $("#ddlBrands").change();
        $("#ddlDates").change();
        $("#ddlLocations").change();
        $("#ddlShips").change();

        //Only after we have finished populating and updating the selects do we show them
        //Prevents flicker on certain mobile devices and their native browsers
        $('#SearchOptions').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

I display the page and make a selection from Brand (which ultimately populates the ship drop down) and I then select a ship, so that I end up with:

[image: After making selection]

I press a button to perform the search and then I have a link which navigates back in the browser history with:

```
javascript:history.go(-1);
```

however the page now has the ship showing as "All Selected" as per:

[image]

this despite the console output showing that I have ship selected in the drop down (All ships has a value of zero):

[image]

The documentation for bootstrap-select says to call 'Render' if you update the value of the select which I have done. So can anyone point me in the right direction as to why the drop down is not showing the correct (ie selected value) value?

Comment: Why navigate back here?? When you navigate back it will display previous   page which is cached and it won't update your `dropdown`. Instead I suggest to try `location.href`

Comment: I don't want to update the drop down.... This is a mobile app so getting things from cache is exactly what I want as it is not another round trip to the server. I want the drop downs to reflect exactly what the user had previously selected so that they can do another search.